# How to create UITableView and detail view separately

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, ios5

I've created an app using single view based.Now I have to display 15 number of menus and description about each menu.So I thought of using `UITableView` inserting in that.While selecting a cell it should display long text & image content.Do i have to create each `ViewController` for each description or any shortcuts to add description programmatically 
Here is my code for table view

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell...
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"Cell Row #%d", [indexPath row]];

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// open a alert with an OK and cancel button
NSString *alertString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Clicked on row #%d", [indexPath row]];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertString message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

This is for creating `UIAlertView` when cell is touched.

How can i do for long text and image display.Any ideas pls.

Comment: It will depend on the content that you want to show on those 15 view controllers as well as the complexity involved.

Comment: On detail view you can get the clicked index and their you can show its detail view !!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a navigation controller and push tableView on it. On selection of a cell of table you should push a detailView (one detail view for all cells). This works only if you have to show same format of details data in the detailView. Else if you have to different screens for each selection, then you can design all those screens which will also make it heavy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer this is for single cell description..But i need 15 kind of description for 15 cells in tableview..How can i achieve that?

Comment: If the UI design of all the cell description are same, and you only need to change the content of the fields in the description fields, then you can change the contents according to the selected row.index. If all of the description have different UI then you need to design different for all.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single ViewController wich initialize with image and text, inside view controller you should create UITextView and UIImageView. ViewController must be something like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImageView *imageView;
    UITextView *textView;
}

-(id)initWithText:(NSString *)text image:(UIImage *)image;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(id)initWithText:(NSString *)text image:(UIImage *)image {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        //ImageView initialization
        imageView.image = image;
        //TextViewInitialization
        textView.text = text;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

In view controller where table view you can create 2 arrays with corresponding images and text to cells.
Then didSelectRowAtIndexPath: must looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]initWithText:[textArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] image:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this is for single cell description..But i need 15 kind of description for 15 cells in tableview..How can i achieve that?

Comment: You need to populate textArray with 15 different strings. Index of string in array must corresponds to cell...